# How do I declare a String[] in an Arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How do I declare a String[] in an Arraylist? For example I have an unknown/varying amount of movie/trailer pairs. So for each item in the arraylist I want there to be a String[] with a movie name, and trailer url.
I tried some things similar to the following but they don't work:

```
   private ArrayList<String[2]> movieArray= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Why dont you make and use model class `class Movie { String name; String trailer; } ArrayList<Movie> movies;`

Comment: see my answer @Tal C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using model:

```
public class Movie
{
  private String movieName;
  private String trailerUrl;

  public void setMovieName ( String movieName ) 
  {
    this.movieName = movieName;
  }

  public void setTrailerUrl ( String trailerUrl) 
  {
    this.trailerUrl= trailerUrl;
  }

  public void getMovieName () 
  {
    return movieName;
  }

  public void getTrailerUrl () 
  {
    return trailerUrl;
  }

}
```

And then just declare:

```
private ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you want to add one set of data. Do this:

```
Movie objMovie = new Movie();
objMovie.setMovieName("Movie Name");
objMovie.setTrailerUrl("Trailer URL");
movieArrayList.add(objMovie);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
ArrayList<List<String>> movieArray = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> movie = new ArrayList<>();
movie.add("name");
movie.add("url");
movieArray.add(movie);
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public Movie(String name, String url){
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    // getter / setter
}

List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

movies.add(new Movie("name", "url"));
movies.add(new Movie("name2", "url2"));
```

Comment: So I can't do a regular array seeing as I already know it's only 2 elements in each one? I heard its more efficient if we know how many elements we want to put in.

Comment: Yes you can! But as @Selvin suggested, you should create a custom class and make a List of it. See my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
List<String[]> movieArray = new ArrayList<>();

movieArray(new String[] {"trailer1", "trailer2", "..."});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare arrayList of String array as follows:

```
  private ArrayList<String[]> movieArray= new ArrayList<>();
  String[] trailer= new String[3];
  trailer[0] = "Trailer0";
  trailer[1] = "Trailer1";
  movieArray.add(trailer);
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

**This will be helpful for variable size of string arrays.**

Try doing this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> movieArray = new ArrayList<>();

String[] array = {"hi","hi","hi","hi"};

String[] array1 = {"hi","hi"};

movieArray.add(array);
movieArray.add(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
List<String[]> movieArray= new ArrayList<>();
```

I would suggest creating a Movie model and use like below.

```
List<Movie> movieArray= new ArrayList<>();
```

If you really do not like to create a model, you can create a list of map like below.

```
List<Map> movieArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

with above you can store the properties in the map and access it.

Answer (score 1):

`private ArrayList<String[]> movieArray= new ArrayList<>();`